# Is this supposed to be blood?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I was watching a gameplay video, and saw this red effect around the edge of the screen:

[image]

Is the red supposed to be blood, or is it your helmets HUD?  Is there an option to disable it?

Comment: Fair, but actually in that question we did confirm that the red blood from players could be disabled, but that the green blood from biological horrors couldn't.

Comment: Yes but I assume that when you are playing single player you won't bleed because there will be nobody to shoot you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience playing this game, I don't think what you see is blood. There are extremes for different games, ranging from Call of Duty (ludicrous amounts of red jelly on your screen) to simple flashes when you take damage (think Hollowknight or similar). For No Man's Sky, your screen just starts to turn red as you take more damage, or alert more enemies.

Honestly though, [the game is rated T for Animated Blood and Fantasy Violence](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/34467/No+Mans+Sky/), so based on your previous question, it might just be best to look for a new title to play.

Comment: Yeah, to me it looks more like either a flash of pain, or your helmet informing you that you've been hit.  Thankfully Hello Games thoughtfully added an option to disable the red blood, so there's only a little green blood when you shoot biological horrors.  Thnx for the answer.  =)

Comment: Yeah, almost positive that it's just HUD on your helmet, as that part of the helmet takes several hues during gameplay, like green.

Answer (score 1):

It's not blood. Just an abstract visual representation of "taking damage."

If you're playing PC, I believe the option to turn it off is "Vignettes and Scanlines" in the Video Options, but I could be wrong as some HUD effects like weather can't be disabled except through mods.